# Extending textarea contained in a div

Tags: html, css, forms

I have a textarea which is contained in a div as I have jquery hint and wanted to use opacity without changing the border.
When I am typing in the text field and it goes beyond the container I cannot see what I am typing. How do I make the div follow the text.

Textfield:

```
<label><div id="name">
                          <textarea name="name" type="text" id="name" title="Enter Message Here" rows=9 cols=60 maxlength="2000"></textarea>

                      </label>
```

Styles:

```
#name { 
    border: 1px solid #c810ca;
    width: 270px;
    height:159px;
    }
```

Comment: Any chance you could edit your question a bit for readability? It also wouldn't hurt to accept some of the correct answers to your previous questions.

Comment: Please check your wrong code... No closing div tag. You use the id="name" twice...

Answer (score 2):

Try to improve basic things:

1. Don't use any id name more than once (you have `div#name` and `textarea#name`, it can cause problems)
2. Close tags in correct order
3. Textarea doesn't support `text` attribute

If it won't solve you problem, please give some more details - I've tested your code and I can see what I'm typing. If you mean to make `div`'s height flexible (although textarea has constant height, it is still resizeable), remove the `height` and replace it by `min-height`.

Comment: Using multiple ids will definitely create problems, only first element with same id get called when any kind of method being applied. i don't know whether your answer solved OP's problem but you deserved +1.